# AWS EC2 Linux: Cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, google-chrome, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get (specific versions of) Chrome and Chromedriver (and ultimately Selenium) running on an AWS EC2 Linux instance that was handed over to me for testing. Following the first four steps of [this](https://understandingdata.com/install-google-chrome-selenium-ec2-aws) guide, I

1. navigated into my `/tmp` directory,
2. ran `sudo wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.61/chromedriver_linux64.zip`,
3. unzipped `chromedriver`,
4. and moved `chromedriver` into my `/usr/bin`.

However, when I go to inspect `chromedriver - version` for a sanity check, I get the following error:

> chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Several posts on this and other sites documenting similar quandaries (error while loading shared libraries: <...>) suggest that maybe this error is due to the absence of `libxcb` from my instance, but I am such a novice that I'm just not sure (I don't even know what `libxcb` is for).  Hoping to get some feedback on how to proceed.  If any other info about my instance would be helpful, feel free to let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Downloading and installing software manually is not a good idea. Install `chromedriver` by using the package manager of your Linux distribution instead.

Comment: sudo yum install libxcb

Answer (score 3):

If you type `yum whatprovides libxcb.so.1` you will see the name and version of the library that provides the file you are missing.

Generally, I found out that libX11 provides most libraries needed for chrome and chromedriver. So try:

```
sudo yum install -y libX11
```

and then repeat the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Chrome binaries, which are required by chromedriver.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

This installs Chrome and required graphic libraries. Worked on my EC2 amazon linux 2.